# test on fold change of the mean vs. mean of fold changes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, inference, biostatistics, bioinformatics

Suppose we have 5 subjects. For each subject, biomarker is measured at t0, t1 and t2. Measured values are skewed. We want to compare the values at t1 and t2.

When we have skewed data, usually we do log-transformation. t test on log-transformed data is equivalent to comparing the fold change of the mean, which is also equivalent to comparing the geometric mean.

I can also calculate fold change for each subject at t1 and t2, both using t0 as baseline. If we do t test on the fold changes at t1 and t2, Are we comparing the mean of fold changes?

So the problem is `fold change of the mean` vs `mean of fold changes`.

If what we want to know is if there is any differences between t1 and t2, in terms of fold change, should we use fold change of the mean OR mean of the fold changes?
Fold change and logFC is commonly used in differential gene analysis. I'm trying to get a better understanding of this issue.

See the example below. All test results are different....

```
# we have 5 subjects. Each subject is tested at t0, t1 and t2. 
t0=c(0.2,0.3,0.5,0.2,0.1)
t1 = t0+runif(5,min=0.5,max=2)
t2 = t1+runif(5, min=0.5, max=1)
t0_log2 = log2(t0)
t1_log2 = log2(t1)
t2_log2 = log2(t2)
t0_fc = t0/t0
t1_fc = t1/t0
t2_fc = t2/t0

# test the diff of log-transformed result between t1 and t2
t.test(t1_log2, t2_log2, paired=T)
# test the diff of fold change (both vs t0) between t1 and t2
t.test(t1_fc, t2_fc, paired=T)

# test the diff of log-transformed result between t0 and t1
t.test(t1_log2, t0_log2, paired=T)
# test the diff of log-transformed result between t0 and t1
t.test(t1_fc, t0_fc, paired=T)
```

How do we properly interpret the results from t test above?

I really appreciate if anyone can clarify my confusion. Thank a lot.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "fold change"?  From your initial comments it looks like you might want to learn about the [geometric mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=geometric+mean).

Comment: @whuber  test log2(result) means testing the fold change of the mean, which is geomean on original result.  However,  does it also make sense to test the mean of fold change? just like the last part of the code.

Comment: @user158565  I modified the answer to make it clearer. No exactly the duplicate from the other question. Also the other question is not answered. Please modify your comment. Thanks.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is a very similar question from you so it would help if you clarified here how this one differs from that one.